# Create a bootstrap header and reuse it on every page

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I am trying to create a header section that can be use on every page using angularjs. I have seen one example using ng-include. But when i tried i am getting an error.
Here is my index.html which try to include the header file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="css/style1.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<!-- font CSS -->
<!-- font-awesome icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome-animation/dist/font-awesome-animation.min.css">
<link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!-- //font-awesome icons -->
 <!-- js-->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

<script src="js/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src= "js/moment-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body class="cbp-spmenu-push" ng-app>
    <div class="main-content">
        <!-- header-starts -->
        <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my header.html file which i want to include.

```
<div class="sticky-header header-section ">
            <div class="header-left">
                <!--toggle button start-->
                <button id="showLeftPush"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                <!--toggle button end-->
                <!--logo -->
                <div class="logo" style="width: 229px">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <span>Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!--//logo-->
                 <div class="search-box">
                    <form class="input">
                        <input class="sb-search-input input__field--madoka" placeholder="Search..." type="search" id="input-31"/>
                        <label class="input__label" for="input-31">
                            <svg class="graphic" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 404 77" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                                <path d="m0,0l404,0l0,77l-404,0l0,-77z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </label>
                    </form>
                </div><!--//end-search-box -->
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header-right">
                <div class="profile_details_left"><!--notifications of menu start -->
                    <ul class="nofitications-dropdown">
                        <li class="dropdown head-dpdn">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-envelope faa-shake animated"></i><span class="badge">3</span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="notification_header">
                                        <h3>You have 3 new messages</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                   <div class="user_img"><img src="images/1.png" alt=""></div>
                                   <div class="notification_desc">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                                    <p><span>1 hour ago</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                                </a></li>
                                <li class="odd"><a href="#">
                                    <div class="user_img"><img src="images/2.png" alt=""></div>
                                   <div class="notification_desc">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet </p>
                                    <p><span>1 hour ago</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                  <div class="clearfix"></div>  
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                   <div class="user_img"><img src="images/3.png" alt=""></div>
                                   <div class="notification_desc">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet </p>
                                    <p><span>1 hour ago</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                                </a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="notification_bottom">
                                        <a href="#">See all messages</a>
                                    </div> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown head-dpdn">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bell faa-ring animated"></i><span class="badge blue">3</span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="notification_header">
                                        <h3>You have 3 new notification</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                    <div class="user_img"><img src="images/2.png" alt=""></div>
                                   <div class="notification_desc">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet</p>
                                    <p><span>1 hour ago</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                  <div class="clearfix"></div>  
                                 </a></li>
                                 <li class="odd"><a href="#">
                                    <div class="user_img"><img src="images/1.png" alt=""></div>
                                   <div class="notification_desc">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet </p>
                                    <p><span>1 hour ago</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                                 </a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">
                                    <div class="user_img"><img src="images/3.png" alt=""></div>
                                   <div class="notification_desc">
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor amet </p>
                                    <p><span>1 hour ago</span></p>
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                                 </a></li>
                                 <li>
                                    <div class="notification_bottom">
                                        <a href="#">See all notifications</a>
                                    </div> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                        <li class="dropdown head-dpdn">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-tasks "></i><span class="badge blue1">15</span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="notification_header">
                                        <h3>You have 8 pending task</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                    <div class="task-info">
                                        <span class="task-desc">Database update</span><span class="percentage">40%</span>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="bar yellow" style="width:40%;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                    <div class="task-info">
                                        <span class="task-desc">Dashboard done</span><span class="percentage">90%</span>
                                       <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                         <div class="bar green" style="width:90%;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                    <div class="task-info">
                                        <span class="task-desc">Mobile App</span><span class="percentage">33%</span>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                                    </div>
                                   <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                         <div class="bar red" style="width: 33%;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">
                                    <div class="task-info">
                                        <span class="task-desc">Issues fixed</span><span class="percentage">80%</span>
                                       <div class="clearfix"></div> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                         <div class="bar  blue" style="width: 80%;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="notification_bottom">
                                        <a href="#">See all pending tasks</a>
                                    </div> 
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                <!--notification menu end -->
                <div class="profile_details">       
                    <ul>
                        <li class="dropdown profile_details_drop">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <div class="profile_img">   
                                    <span class="prfil-img"><img src="images/a.png" alt=""> </span> 
                                    <div class="user-name">
                                        <span>Administrator</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down lnr"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-angle-up lnr"></i>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>    
                                </div>  
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu drp-mnu">
                                <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>               
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>   
        </div>
```

The error i am getting is:
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/gaurav/Documents/newadmin/adminpanel/header.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: If you have node installed in your system, just install one more package globally (http-server) like this npm i http-server -g. After installed, visit to the root folder in cmd and type http-server. It will show you the port on which your application will be running

Comment: I think you are running these files without using a server. Deploy these files on some server (like Apache). then this will work.

Comment: Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://192.168.200.149:8080
  http://192.168.200.155:8080
I am getting this

Comment: @gauravtiwari use any one of them and run in browser

Comment: Thanx @pac-man  its working fine now. I have one doubt that ng-include has any dependency with server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of `file:// protocol.` Mostly all browsers disallow `XHR` requests when file is been served from `file://.` That is why AJAX requests are failing. And `ng-include` use them to download files.

You can launch Chrome with `--allow-file-access-from-files` parameter to disable checks for `file://.`

FireFox should load files if they are in same folder (check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3A_URIs) for more info).

Hope this helps.